# python class using pyodbc. Error on multiple rows

Tags: python, pyodbc

This piece of code prints out one line of data which is expected. It prints out "None" in the second row which I would like an explanation on as well but it is not the main question

```
rows = cursor.fetchone()
for row in rows:
    cur = SHIPMENT_BO(row.SHIPMENT_NUM, row.SHIPMENT_ID, row.ORIGIN_BRANCH_CODE, row.DEST_BRANCH_CODE)
    print(cur.PrintShipment())
```

This code only returns the first print statement in the function but none of the data.

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    cur = SHIPMENT_BO(row.SHIPMENT_NUM, row.SHIPMENT_ID, row.ORIGIN_BRANCH_CODE, row.DEST_BRANCH_CODE)
    print(cur.PrintShipment())
```

Here is the class I call above

```
class SHIPMENT_BO:

    def __init__(self, shipNo, shipId, origBranch, destBranch):
        self.__shipmentNo = shipNo
        self.__shipmentID = shipId
        self.__originBranch = origBranch
        self.__destinationBranch = destBranch


    def PrintShipment(self):
        print("Shipment No, Shipment ID, Origin Branch, Destination Branch")
        print(self.__shipmentNo + " " + str(self.__shipmentID) + " " + self.__originBranch + " " + self.__destinationBranch)
```

If I print the shipment number directly it prints millions of rows as expected

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row.SHIPMENT_NUM)
    #cur = SHIPMENT_BO(row.SHIPMENT_NUM, row.SHIPMENT_ID, row.ORIGIN_BRANCH_CODE, row.DEST_BRANCH_CODE)
    #print(cur.PrintShipment())
```

My first question is why does the code and class work for one row but not for multiple rows? My second question is why do I get a "None" print after the code with one row? Lastly this code does not work at all (none of the print statements execute), surely you would get at least the one row you have selected in the cursor.

```
rows = cursor.fetchone()
for row in rows:
    cur = SHIPMENT_BO(row.SHIPMENT_NUM, row.SHIPMENT_ID, row.ORIGIN_BRANCH_CODE, row.DEST_BRANCH_CODE)
    print(cur.PrintShipment())
```

Answer (score 1):

**re: fetchone() vs. fetchall()**

By using ...

```python
rows = cursor.fetchone()
for row in rows:
```

... it looks like you expect pyodbc's `fetchone()` method to return a list containing a single tuple for the one row fetched, but it doesn't. It returns a `pyodbc.Row` object. When you iterate over that object you are actually iterating over the *column values* for that row:

```python
sql = """\
SELECT 'foo' AS col1, 42 AS col2
"""
rows = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

will print

```
foo
42
```

On the other hand, `fetchall()` does return a list (of `pyodbc.Row` objects), so it behaves more like you would expect

```python
sql = """\
SELECT 'foo' AS col1, 42 AS col2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar' AS col1, 123 AS col2
"""
rows = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

will print

```
('foo', 42)
('bar', 123)
```

**re: printing `None` after each row**

When you do

```python
print(cur.PrintShipment())
```

You invoke your `PrintShipment` method, which includes its own `print()` function calls to display the column headings and column data. Then after the `PrintShipment` method returns you are `print`-ing the *return value* of the `PrintShipment` method, which is `None` because it doesn't include a `return` statement. To avoid printing the spurious `None` values just call the method itself:

```python
cur.PrintShipment()  # not wrapped in a print() function
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains my issue with the "None" being printed after the single line query. Do you have any idea why the class is not working for multiple rows but works for a single row. As I mentioned above if you print the row.SHIPMENT_NUM explicitly then it prints millions of rows in the for loop, so the data is getting extracted. Is there something incorrect in my syntax that I am not seeing or am not understanding? Why does the class work for one row but not many?

Comment: @lem - *"Do you have any idea why the class is not working"* - Not really. [This](http://pastebin.com/UsvrYWWj) works fine for me.